# Getting this error while trying to connect facebook chat using smack

Tags: java, facebook, chat, smack

Getting this error while trying to connect facebook chat using smack.
jars used smack 3.3.1.jar,smackx 3.3.1.jar

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.jivesoftware.smackx.ServiceDiscoveryManager$1.connectionCreated(Lorg/jivesoftware/smack/Connection;)V
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.initConnection(XMPPConnection.java:652)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:604)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:1022)
        at com.FacebookChatSample.main(FacebookChatSample.java:30)
```

Comment: Could you provide some snippet of `FacebookChatSample.java`?

Comment: ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com",5222,"facebook.com");
    config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
    
    SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism.class);
    SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM", 0);
   connection.connect();
    String apiKey ="MYKEY";
    String accessToken ="MYTOKEN";
    connection.login(apiKey, accessToken);
    }

Comment: FROM HERE I HAVE TAKEN CODE FOR SASLXFacebookPlatformMechanism class  https://gist.github.com/btd/8596391

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem. Turned out that I didn't put the right package in my pom.xml

I used the following Maven dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jivesoftware</groupId>
    <artifactId>smack</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and it gave me the error when I tried to connect to my server. When I changed it to :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
    <artifactId>smackx</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

it worked.

**Note :** smack dependency was another entry from the beggining and should be left this way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
    <artifactId>smack</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Note 2 :** I didn't explixitly use anything from smackx, it is used in XMPPConnection.initConnection() there where it tries to inform all the ConnectionCreationListener listeners that a connection has just been established.